# How to Force Aero Peek to Stay Up

Tags: windows, video, taskbar, aero-peek

Let's say I have a video running in an application.  If I hover my mouse over the taskbar, it shows a little popup windows that diplays the video  (aero peek).  Sometimes I'm running a maximized window and I want to have this little screen always popped up.

(Kind've like when your using the TV Guide menu, you still see a little clip of the video)

Comment: Leave your mouse hovering over the taskbar icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OnTopReplica](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/ontopreplica)

> I remember that since Windows 95 or so, I always wanted to find a way to watch a movie on my PC while coding, writing or doing some other work (keeping it "always on top"). Finally, with Vista and its "DWM Desktop Composition" I was able to create a simple application that does simply that: you can clone whatever window is on your screen and watch it in a small thumbnail that always keeps on top of all other windows (even if it hasn't mouse focus).

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is a small box that stays on top of the current window why not use [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)?

In the *Video* menu click *Always on Top*. You can then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to switch to 'Minimal View'. You can obviously move and resize this window to meet your needs.

[image: vlc video in a tiny box]

Comment: Classic Media Player is also an option with a 'stay on top' ability, and shrinks down to smaller sizes

Answer (score 1):

[Videoinpicture](http://videoinpicture.wikidot.com/) does this kind of thing.

[image]

```
* Watch videos in a "picture in picture" type box. Very useful for online videos where you have lots of content you don't want to be shown while you watch videos.
* Create live thumbnail previews that stay put. Close them by double-clicking on the preview.
* Resize the thumbnail previews by dragging the borders.
* Crop thumbnail previews by holding down the Ctrl key and dragging the borders. Get rid of all that white space around your YouTube videos you watch!
* Move the previews around and dock them to any edge of the screen.
* Make the previews stay on top of all other windows.
* Make the previews transparent, both visually and to input. This means that you can see through the previews and click on items beneath it! Very useful when you want to watch a video while doing other work in another window.
* Create these special thumbnail previews easily by using a tray icon or even easier, by just minimizing the window!
```